# highstock dual axis tooltip placement

Tags: javascript, tooltip, highcharts

I have a single highstock chart with 2 y-axis - one displaying an area chart and below it a column chart.

I am trying to achieve 2 things (both of which I know are possible, just not sure how to do it).

1. have a single tooltip, not the 3 that are currently showing up
2. have that tooltip follow the cursor - either tracking the cursor as
   it move across the screen, or appear only over the chart which is
   being hovered over (in reality the charts will be larger than the
   codepen and require the page to be scrolled).

Appreciate any help!

```
$cumulative_chart = Highcharts.stockChart('container', {
    chart: {
        type: 'area',
        height: 500
    },
    plotOptions: {
        series: {
            //stacking: 'normal',
            dataGrouping: {
                units: [[
                    'day',
                    [1]
                ], [
                    'month',
                    [1, 3, 6]
                ], [
                    'year',
                    null
                ]]
            }
        }
    },
    yAxis: [{
        height: '50%'
    }, {
        top: '65%',
        height: '50%',
        offset: 0
    }],
     xAxis: {
        offset: 100
    },
    credits: {
        enabled: false
    },
    tooltip: {
            enabled: true,
            shared: true
        },
    series: [{
            type: 'area',
            data: [[1512086400000, 10626],[1512172800000, 21634],[1512259200000, 34994],[1512345600000, 51400],[1512432000000, 68430]],
            stack: 0,
            name: 'chart A',
            id: 'area'
        },
        {
            type: 'column',
            data: [[1512086400000, 10626],[1512172800000, 11008],[1512259200000, 13360],[1512345600000, 16406],[1512432000000, 17030]],
            stack: 1,
            name: 'chart B',
            yAxis: 1,
            id: 'column',
            showInLegend: false
        }]
});
```

codepen: https://codepen.io/anon/pen/ZozBZM

Comment: I'm not entirely sure, but I think adding `split:false` to your tooltip will solve majority of your problem http://jsfiddle.net/ta5et9uc/17/

Comment: genius! I missed this entirely. That solved it.

Answer (score 0):

The option you are looking for is to add `split:false` to your tooltip. This causes for the tooltip to center itsself around one of your graphs, instead of hovering over all the graphs in your highstock chart.

A working fiddle is found [here](http://jsfiddle.net/ta5et9uc/17)

You can find more information in the [highcharts API](https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.pareto.tooltip.split)